# Remove decimal 0 from number in PHP

Tags: php, e-commerce

Need to remove zeros after number in decimals
so for example `100,01201500` will become `100,012015`

I have now this function:

```
php echo number_format($plan['price'], 0, '.', '' ) - this remove all decimals

$plan['price'] = 100,12345

echo number_format($plan['price'], 0, '.', '' ) = 100
```

But I need to make `echo ($plan['price']) = 100,12345`

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) them off?

```
echo rtrim(number_format(…), '0');
```